# Application Insight Missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure-application-insights

I can't seem to find Application Insight in Visual Studio anywhere. The MS documentation tells me to:

- Run an Asp.Net core project on IIS Express
- Select View > Other Windows > Application Insights Search

But it isn't there. Nore is it anywhere else in Visual Studio.

I have the ASP.NET and web development workload installed (all options checked).

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. (It's driving me absolutely nuts)

Thanks for your help!

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the 'Developer Analytics Tools' extension was disabled.

I probably disabled it previously myself because of al the (pretty annoying) pop-ups at the introduction of AI. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.